# Change the order in parsing subcommands / positional argument in Rust Clap?

Tags: rust, clap

The following code works but does not do what I want

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;
use clap::{Args, Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Cli {

    #[command(subcommand)]
    command: Commands,

    dir: PathBuf,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    Add,
    Scrub,
    Check,
}
```

It parses the command line arguments as `<DIR> <COMMAND>` but I would like `<COMMAND> <DIR>` instead.

One option would be to do

```rust
#[derive(Args)]
struct CommandArgs {
    dir: PathBuf,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    Add(CommandArgs), 
    Scrub(CommandArgs),
    Check(CommandArgs),
}
```

But the fact that the CLI expect `<COMMAND> <DIR>` is totally hidden in `--help`. One has to put the command first to find out about the positional argument. **But all my commands have a `<DIR>` parameter**, so I would like the `--help` to reflect that.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can make `dir` `#[arg(global = true)]`, but unfortunately that means [it has to be optional as well](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/1546) and it doesn't change the documented order either.